# I cannot connect to my mongodb database - why?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb installed and I have the following entries in `mongod.conf`:

```
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: [0.0.0.0]

security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Now, in database earlier on I create 2 users with the following queries:

```
use admin
db.createUser({user: "user1", pwd:"myPass1", roles: [{ role: "root", db: "admin"}]})

db.createUser({user: "user2", pwd:"myPass2", roles: [{ role: "readWrite", db: "myCollection"}, { role: "read", db: "myCollection"}]})
```

when I do

```
sudo service mongod stop
sudo mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

and I type:

```
sudo mongo admin -u user1 -p myPass1
```

I'm getting error:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin
MongoDB server version: 3.4.3
2017-04-03T13:56:30.687+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1459:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed
```

However, when I comment out the lines:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

from `mongo.conf` then I can log in to my mongo with command `sudo mongo` (without providing any credentials).

How can I log in to mongo, while keeping it secure and disallow logging in without user and password?

Comment: did you tried : sudo mongo admin -u user1 -p

Comment: yes, same result

Comment: Try logging in with `mongo admin -u user1 -p myPass1 --authenticationDatabase admin`

Comment: hm I tried that too and unfortunatelly I cannot connect either...

Comment: when I type `sudo mongo` I can connect, but then anything I type (e.g. `show databases`) brings me to `listDatabases failed, code: Unauthorized`)

Comment: are you able to log in as "user2"?